# Raspberry pi 2 B + Selenium Java = WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect

Tags: java, linux, selenium-webdriver, firefox, raspberry-pi2

I've tried to use Selenium for Java, it's works perfect on Windows 10, but not on my Raspberry Pi 2 B, I've got an error.

Code line in error:
`driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);`

Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to > localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:13054
> Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
> System info: host: 'Domoticz', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'arm', os.version: '5.10.17-> v7+', java.version: '11.0.9.1'
> Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
> at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
> at com.seleniumtest.seleniumtest.Test.run(Test.java:73)
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:13054
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:247)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:165)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
> at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
> at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
> at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
> at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
> ... 5 more
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connexion refusée (Connection refused)
> at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
> at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
> at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
> at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
> at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:129)
> at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:245)
> ... 27 more

Pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
 ​<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
 ​<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
 ​<version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Drivers used :

```
     ​- geckodriver-v0.27.0-linux32.tar

     ​- geckodriver-v0.28.0-linux32.tar

​     - geckodriver-v0.29.1-linux32.tar
```

Firefox version :
`Mozilla Firefox 78.10.0esr`

Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: ...does the driver start? Do you see the browser?

Comment: The program run with some options :

`FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();`

`firefoxOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");`

`firefoxOptions.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");`

`firefoxOptions.addArguments("--headless");`

`firefoxOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");`

`firefoxOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");`

`driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);`

Comment: The driver don't start

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue : i must use a arm driver and not a linux32 :
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.23.0